# Include column headers in csv exported using filehelpers v2.0

Tags: c#, filehelpers

How can I add a header row to the CSV output from FileHelper v2.0?

I've seen listings with answers that must predate this version as things like FieldOrder and FieldTitle are not valid attributes and GetFileHeader is not a valid mathod for the filehelper engine.

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried already?

Comment: Agreed, please post the code you are using so that we can diagnose it properly.  There are multiple engines within FileHelpers, so it may be down to the one that you are using...

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code? GetFileHeader should be valid...

```
var fh = new FileHelperEngine<Foo>();
fh.HeaderText = fh.GetFileHeader();
```

Comment: Intellisense does not show the GetFileHeader method and if I type it in anyway it doesn't compile.